# Sum multiple rasters using raster calculator, the result raster had a larger cell size?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, raster-calculator, cell-size

I have 365 rasters (daily) and therefore I summed them to form an annual raster using raster calculator in Arcgis. The original cell size of daily raster is 5*3.75 (col 72, row 48), while the cell size of the annual raster is 5*5 (col 72, row 36). The cell size became larger automatically. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 2):

You can control the cell size from the `ArcToolbox -> Geoprocessing Environment ->` [Cell size](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/environment-settings/cell-size.htm). Also another way to sum all rasters is to use [Cell Statistics](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool with SUM type for such a task. Here is an illustration from the help page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But, the problem still remains. I controlled the cell size (set as Same as the daily raster layer), and I also used arcpy (arcpy.env.cellSize = "daily raster"). They both did not work.  The potential reason might be the default output resolution was determined by the coarsest of X and Y of the cell size. Even though we can set the cell size equals to X（if X<Y), I did not find a solution to control  X and Y at the same time. It seems that the cell size of output raster has to be a square (X=Y).